# Android KitKat MediaScannerConnection not finding images saved to private app folder

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an app which performs processing on an image selected by the user using from the gallery, after processing the modified image is then saved back to the original image's folder with a modified filename. On specific devices (mainly Samsungs) the new KitKat permission limitations severely limit where a non system app can write to e.g. external SD card or back to typical gallery locations.
The documentation advises to write to the private package specific folder obtained via

```
getExternalFilesDir(null)
```

This is fine and the image is saved correctly but then a subsequent call to

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile
```

fails to update the central media database correctly as the modified image doesn't appear in the gallery, even a reboot of the device which should force a full scan of all media doesn't trigger the image to be displayed.

In other words the following code doesn't work:

```
File appDir = MyActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir(null);
File file = new File(appDir, "new_image.jpeg");
// Process image and write file away...
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file.getAbsolutePath() }, null, new        MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Scanned file: %s", path));
  }
});
```

The onScanCompleted method fires but the gallery doesn't show the new image.

Has anyone seen this behaviour, does MediaScanner not scan 'private' app folders and if so how else do I get the gallery to detect and display the new image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want images to be picked up by the gallery, you should put them in the proper public location. You can get the proper location using [Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)).

Comment: But the new permission limitations in KitKat (if enforced by the hardware provider e.g. Samsung Galaxy Note 3) prohibit a normal app from writing to this location according to http://source.android.com/devices/tech/storage/index.html.

Comment: If you have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, you can write to this location.

Comment: Krylez, the docs say "The WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission must only grant write access to the primary external storage on a device. Apps must not be allowed to write to secondary external storage devices" I'm really confused by what constitutes primary and secondary external storage, additionally I don't have a Samsung device to test this on and the Android emulator running KitKat doesn't honour/enforce these restrictions which is quite ironic.

Comment: It's a confusing subject. Environment.getExternaltStoragePublicDirectory() will always be on _primary_ external storage, so you can write to it (with permission). Keep in mind that the SD card is very often, but not always, _primary_ external storage. Dave Smith gives the most complete explanation of all of this: http://www.doubleencore.com/2014/03/android-external-storage/

Comment: Krylez, thanks for that link, that gives a very good explanation and hopefully clarifies where I may be going wrong.